# How do I install websocket module for Node.js on Debian VPS?

Tags: node.js, websocket, debian, vps

I have successfully installed Node.js, now I want to install the websocket module found here: https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node

From the root user, I have run the following command:

```
 npm install websocket
```

The error thrown is:

> [websocket v1.0.7]

```
Native code compile failed!!

On Windows, native extensions require Visual Studio and Python.

On Unix, native extensions require Python, make and a C++ compiler.

Start npm with --websocket:verbose to show compilation output (if any).
```

What commands should I issue to install this websocket module and its requirements?

Edit:
When I run `sudo apt-get install gcc make`

I get this message:

> Reading package lists... Done 
>   Building dependency tree 
>   Reading state information... Done 
>   gcc is already the newest version. 
>   gcc set to manually installed. 
>   make is already the newest version. 
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.

And the same error when trying to install WebSocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed python, make and gcc.
Python should be already installed by default.
You can install gcc and make as root with command:

```
apt-get install gcc make
```

Comment: Bizarre, I'm still getting the same error as above. I'll add to the original post.

Comment: The same error occurs, additionally I have tried the -g and link commands.

Comment: Can you try to install it with this command: `npm install websocket --websocket:verbose` Then you should see better error message.

Comment: Thank you! I rebooted the server and it worked. However I'm unable to find the websocket module by running on my other user. I know why, and I'm going to reinstall node properly by resetting my VPS. This has been a great learning experience, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the install.js, this error is because you got problems with node-gyp.
Try "sudo npm install -g node-gyp" and run your commands again.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get g++
```

fixed my problem, very nice!

Answer (score 0):

My problem: python version. I have installed python 2.4.3 instead python 2.7 (required for websocket).

I [install python2.7](http://elastic-computing.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/install-python-27-on-centos-without.html) with **make altinstall** and create a symbolic link for replace python script:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

And works for me:

```
# npm install websocket --websocket:verbose

[websocket v1.0.8] Attempting to compile native extensions.
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.15/node-v0.10.15.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.15/node-v0.10.15.tar.gz
make: Entering directory `********/node_modules/websocket/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/xor/src/xor.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/xor.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/xor.node: Finished
  COPY Release/xor.node
make: Leaving directory `*******/node_modules/websocket/build'
[websocket v1.0.8] Native extension compilation successful!
```